# Spray Routing Akka Ask Pattern

Tags: spray

In the following example:

```
val route =
    path("tsdb-consumer" / "tsdbPing") {
      get {
        respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
          onComplete(worker ? PingTsdb) {
            case Success(res) => complete(res) // Line 1: res if of Type Any
            case Failure(ex) => complete(InternalServerError, Map("error" -> ex.getMessage))
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

How could I get the expected type at Line 1 in my snippet above? All I would like to do is get the response from the Actor as pipe it to the client as a String!

Comment: What does worker return back? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: I figured that out! I had to do a mapTo on the Future!